# Gradle unable to resolve the package from external dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have two gradle projects:

- core project (Built `jar` file for this)
- client project (This uses the core project)

For the client project, I added the jar file dependency (`local jar file`) in `build.gradle` like below:

```
    implementation files('/core-service/build/libs/food-app-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

I can see that core project dependencies are resolving in the client project:
[image]

But, when I add it in the client project, I get errors like this:
[image]

It is not properly detecting the package/package structure.

I'm not sure whats going wrong here. Is there anything I need to add in `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle` ?